# Raytracing and Computer Graphics. Color perception functions

Tags: graphics, raytracing

## Summary

This is a question about how to map light intensity values, as calculated in a raytracing model, to color values percieved by humans. I have built a ray tracing model, and found that including the inverse square law for calculation of light intensities produces graphical results which I believe are unintuitive. I think this is partly to do with the limited range of brightness values available with 8 bit color images, but more likely that I should *not* be using a linear map between light intensity and pixel color.

## Background

I developed a recent interest in creating computer graphics with raytracing techniques.

A basic raytracing model might work something like this

- Calculate ray vectors from the center of the camera (eye) in the direction of each screen pixel to be rendered
- Perform vector collision tests with all objects in the world
- If collision, make a record of the color of the object at the point where the collision occurs
- Create a new vector from the collision point to the nearest light
- Multiply the color of the light by the color of the object

This creates reasonable, but flat looking images, even when surface normals are included in the calculation.

## Model Extensions

My interest was in trying to extend this model by including the distance into the light calculations.

If an object is lit by a light at distance `d`, then if the object is moved a distance `2d` from the light source the illumination intensity is reduced by a factor of 4. This is the inverse square law.

It doesn't apply to all light models. (For example light arriving from an infinite distance has intensity independent of the position of an object.)

From playing around with my code I have found that this inverse square law doesn't produce the realistic lighting I was hoping for.

For example, I built some initial objects for a model of a room/scene, to test things out.

- There are some objects at a distance of 3-5 from the camera.
- There are walls which make a boundry for the room, and I have placed them with distance of order 10 to 100 from the camera.
- There are some lights, distance of order 10 from the camera.

What I have found is this

- If the boundry of the room is more than distance 10 from the camera, the color values are very dim.
- If the boundry of the room is a distance 100 from the camera it is completely invisible.

This doesn't match up with what I would expect intuitively. It makes sense mathematically, as I am using a linear function to translate between color intensity and RGB pixel values.

## Discussion

Moving an object from a distance 10 to a distance 100 reduces the color intensity by a factor of `(100/10)^2 = 100`. Since pixel RGB colors are in the range of 0 - 255, clearly a factor of 100 is significant and would explain why an object at distance 10 moved to distance 100 becomes completely invisible.

However, I suspect that the human perception of color is non-linear in some way, and I assume this is a problem which has already been solved in computer graphics. (Otherwise raytracing engines wouldn't work.)

My guess would be there is some kind of color perception function which describes how absolute light intensities should be mapped to human perception of light intensity / color.

Does anyone know anything about this problem or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here's one resource I found: [Realistic Raytracing](https://web.cs.wpi.edu/~emmanuel/courses/cs563/write_ups/zackw/realistic_raytracing.html).  Amazon has several books that cover the subject of ray tracing.

Comment: If the walls of a room are 100m away from all the lights, then it makes sense that you can't see them.  The distance from the camera is not relevant.

Comment: @MattTimmermans That doesn't make any sense. Does reality work like this?

Comment: Yes! Regarding distance from the camera:  If the object moves twice as far away from the camera, then each square inch of it sends 1/4 as much light to the camera, but 4 times as many square inches of it fit into each pixel, so the perceived brightness of the surface is unchanged.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I came to the same conclusion, and after implementing this change in code I could see the walls, as I expected to be able to... so your previous comment didn't make any sense to me. Still we appear to agree on the physics.

Answer (score 0):

> If an object is lit by a light at distance d, then if the object is moved a distance 2d from the light source the illumination intensity is reduced by a factor of 4. This is the inverse square law.

The physical quantity you're describing here is not intensity, but [radiant flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux). For a discussion of radiometric concepts in the context of ray tracing, see [Chapter 5.4 of Physically Based Rendering](https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Color_and_Radiometry/Radiometry).

> If the boundary of the room is more than distance 10 from the camera, the color values are very dim.
> If the boundary of the room is a distance 100 from the camera it is completely invisible.

The inverse square law can be a useful first approximation for point lights in a ray tracer (before more accurate lighting models are implemented). The key point is that the law - radiant flux falling off by the square of the distance - applies only to the light from the point source to a surface, *not* to the light that's then reflected from the surface to the camera.

In other words, moving the camera back from the scene shouldn't reduce the brightness of the objects in the rendered image; it should only reduce their size.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't very clear - in the end I actually solved the problem, but the solution was the inverse of what you describe. I also initially assumed that the inverse square law should have been used in my lighting calculations. It should, but in only one place, not two places. It is not so obvious why - and difficult to explain without posting what would be a very large amount of code.